# How can you get the pipes on Steamboat Willie to work reliably?

Tags: building, ideas, boat

We recently began building [21317 Steamboat Willie](https://brickset.com/sets/21317-1/Steamboat-Willie).  We've got it mostly built, but the pipes keep getting stuck.  The rear one works, but the front one keeps getting stuck up and won't go down.  We've thoroughly squeezed all of the pieces, but it keeps happening.  Has anyone come up with a reliable design tweak to keep the Steamboat pipes moving?

[image: 21317 Steamboat Willie]

Comment: You may have the Technic mechanism inside the boat too tight. I would take off the top section, and look to make sure that all parts of the moving mechanism works freely even before attaching the smoke stacks.

Comment: We'll give that a try, but we didn't see any of the sticking before we added the brackets for the stacks onto it.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my only guess. I have built this set and experienced no sticking, and there are a bunch of online reviews and video-reviews, and none of the ones I have read/watched mention sticking. I do remember reading one review (unfortunately I don't remember which one), that mentioned the importance of making sure the Technic mechanism works freely as you build it up.

Comment: We saw a thread on the LEGO page on Facebook where other folks had similar problems, but it seems to be gone now.  I wouldn't have posted here if I didn't think it was more ubiquitous.

Comment: This is a real thing.  But the Lego response is to blame the builder.  Sigh.  Check out this fix... it substitutes a 1x2 tile for a 1x2 grill -- which is a fraction thinner and helps with the sticking problem.  https://imgur.com/a/6RdWcxD